# Error when using sqflite_common_ffi instead of sqfilte on Android

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

For targeting mulitple platforms, I want to use sqflite_common_ffi instead of sqflite (sqflite_common_ffi is compatible with Windows).

But when I run my project on Android, I have this exception when running`databaseFactoryFfi.openDatabase` method:

`Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library '/data/data/com.coutier.scool/lib/libsqlite3.so': dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.coutier.scool/lib/libsqlite3.so" not found`

I do not understand : sqlite not supposed to be included in android ? Why this package want to load a specific library ?

If I really need this library to make sqflite_common_ffi run, where can I find this library and where have I to put in my project tree ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS and Android, you can add `sqlite3_flutter_libs` that includes the binaries for iOS and Android. `sqflite_common_ffi` uses `sqlite3` and its default library loader should work as is.

Comment: Did you mean adding both packages to pubspec.yaml?

Comment: @aym1781969 correct, you need to add both sqlite3_flutter_libs (the flutter binaries) and sqflite_common_ffi (which will also include sqlite3)

Comment: Ok thanks another question plz in case I use sqflite_common_ffi  for both desktop and mobile how can I use the databasefactory for both platform?

Comment: yes, some info here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite_common_ffi/doc/using_ffi_instead_of_sqflite.md